# How to create a funtion object for a class member function which defined in macro

Tags: c++, functor

I have something in my CPP like

```
#define DECLARE_some(name, argType, returnType) \
        class myclass##name : public Service::ServiceRpcHandler<a, r> { \
        public: \
            myclass##name(Service *); \
            CONST_STRING getName() const override;\
            void operator()(Service::ServiceRpcHandler<a, r>::type *); \
        };#decleration



 #define IMPLEMENT_Some(name, argType, returnType) \
            class myclass##name::myclass##name(Service * owner) : Service::ServiceRpcHandler<a, r>(o) { } \
            CONST_STRING myclass##name::getName() const { return #name; }\
            void myclass##name::operator()(Service::ServiceRpcHandler<a, r>::type * twk)#implementation of a declared macro
```

All i just want is to create a function object for `void myclass##name::operator()(Service::ServiceRpcHandler<a, r>::type * twk)`. i have understood that `myclass##name::operator()` is itself an functor but anyhow i want to make an another one something like `std::function<(?)(?)>

I have edited as one of the comment suggests

Comment: You need to show a [mcve] of how this macro is used, because it doesn't make any sense to glue "class" and "name" using the token paste operator, `##`.

Comment: @ Sam, thanks that was a typo i made an edit

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing particularly mysterious about creating a function object. In order to create a function object that invokes the constructed class's `()` operator, well, the first thing you need to do is, well, an instance of the class. You can't invoke `operator()` out of thin air. You need an object whose `()` operator your function object will forward to.

```
myclass##name(Service *);
```

The macro creates a class whose constructor takes a `Service *` parameter. So, presuming that the macro is used to construct a class `myclassdisplay`, one way to do this would be:

```
auto f=[](Service *p, Service::ServiceRpcHandler<a, r>::type *arg)
{
    myclassdisplay c(p);

    c(arg);
};
```

The function constructs a new instance of the `myclassdisplay`, and invokes its `()` operator.

You could make this into a macro of its own:

```
#define FUNCTOR(name) [](Service *p, Service::ServiceRpcHandler<a, r>::type *arg)\
{\
    myclass##name c(p);\
\
    c(arg);\
};
```

And then use this in the same fashion:

```
auto f=FUNCTOR(display);
```

Your question isn't clear exactly where the instances of the class come from. This would be the way to have the class instances constructor in the functor wrapper itself. If the class instances are already declared, the sample functor should be modified accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Sam, It helps understanding.